# How to sharex when using subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a Matlab user recently converted to Python. Most of the Python skills I manage on my own, but with plotting I have hit the wall and need some help.

This is what I'm trying to do...

I need to make a figure that consists of 3 subplots with following properties:

- subplot layout is 311, 312, 313
- the height of 312 and 313 is approximately half of the 311
- all subplots share common X axis
- the space between the subplots is 0 (they touch each other at X axis)

By the way I know how to make all this, only not in a single figure. That is the problem I'm facing now.

For example, this is my ideal subplot layout:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1*s2

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (2,0), colspan=3)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (3,0), colspan=3)

ax1.plot(t,s1)
ax2.plot(t[:150],s2[:150])
ax3.plot(t[30:],s3[30:])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Notice how the x axis of different subplots is misaligned. I do not know how to align the x axis in this figure, but if I do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1*s2

fig2, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)

ax1.plot(t,s1)
ax2.plot(t[:150],s2[:150])
ax3.plot(t[30:],s3[30:])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Now the x axis is aligned between the subplots, but all subplots are the same size (which is not what I want)

Furthermore, I would like that the subplots are touching at x axis like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1*s2

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax2 = plt.subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(313, sharex=ax1)

ax1.plot(t,s1)
ax2.plot(t[:150],s2[:150])
ax3.plot(t[30:],s3[30:])

xticklabels = ax1.get_xticklabels()+ax2.get_xticklabels()
plt.setp(xticklabels, visible=False)

plt.show()
```

So to rephrase my question:

I would like to use

```
plt.subplot2grid(..., colspan=3, rowspan=2)
plt.subplots(..., sharex=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

and

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

together in the same figure. How to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just specify `sharex=ax1` when creating your second and third subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1*s2

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (2,0), colspan=3, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (3,0), colspan=3, sharex=ax1)

ax1.plot(t,s1)
ax2.plot(t[:150],s2[:150])
ax3.plot(t[30:],s3[30:])

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)   
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    # The y-ticks will overlap with "hspace=0", so we'll hide the bottom tick
    ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[1:])  

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you still what to use `fig.tight_layout()`, you'll need to call it *before* `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)`.  The reason for this is that `tight_layout` works by automatically calculating parameters for `subplots_adjust` and then calling it, so if `subplots_adjust` is manually called first, anything in the first call to it will be overridden by `tight_layout`.

E.g.

```
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed.
Nice trick to avoid overlapping y-ticks. However, I solved it by mowing the middle y-axis to the right side.
`ax2.yaxis.tick_right()`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to manually create the axis using the `add_axis` method like shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)
s3 = s1*s2

left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.5, width, 0.4]
rect2 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.15]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.15]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1)  #left, bottom, width, height
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2, sharex=ax1)
ax3  = fig.add_axes(rect3, sharex=ax1)

ax1.plot(t,s1)
ax2.plot(t[:150],s2[:150])
ax3.plot(t[30:],s3[30:])

# hide labels
for label1,label2 in zip(ax1.get_xticklabels(),ax2.get_xticklabels()):
    label1.set_visible(False)
    label2.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

But this way you cannot use `tight_layout` as you explicitly define the size of each axis.