# Sharex with 3 subplots with multiple y

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

Basically, I want to stack 3 graphs on top of each other so that they can share the x. The problem is, is that some of the plots use the twinx command(?) because they have 2 or more y axes.

If it's not clear what I mean, I have manually put the graphs together to see how it looks but it's not as nice. (NB/ ignore the lines down the graph and I'd also like no x labels on 1 or 2)

[Example of graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH0e2.png)

Additionally, an example of one of the figures code is shown below - if it helps at all.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.13, bottom=0.12, right=0.91, top=0.9, wspace=0.3, 
hspace=0.5)
plt.margins(x=0)

ax.scatter(data['elapsed_seconds'], Abut_Stress, label='Abutment Stress 
Calculated', linewidth=0, marker='o', s=20,
       c='k')

ax.plot(data['elapsed_seconds'], data['wheel_temp_c'], label='Wheel 
Temperature', linestyle="-", color='b')
ax.plot(data['elapsed_seconds'], data['abut_temp_c'], label='Abutment 
Temperature', linestyle="-", color='g')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data['elapsed_seconds'], data['wheel_speed'], label='Wheel Speed', 
linestyle="-", color='r')

# -------------Get legend names to be plotted in the same legend box-------

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
lg = ax.legend(h1 + h2, l1 + l2, bbox_to_anchor=(0., 0.8, 1., .102), loc=3, 
ncol=1, borderaxespad=0., fontsize=28, )
lg.get_frame().set_linewidth(0.5)

# ----------------------Settings for the first figure window---------------

ax.set_ylim(0, 1000)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 12)
ax.set_xlim(0,data_end)
ax.set_xlabel(r"Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel(r"Abutment Stress (MPa)    Temperature($^\circ$C)")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Wheel Speed (RPM)")

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax2.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
```

Comment: So a the moment you create 3 separate figures, and you would like them all in 1 figure, sharing the x axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sharex when using subplot2grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661526/how-to-sharex-when-using-subplot2grid)

Comment: @DavidG Precisely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple script to do what you want. It uses [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to create the first three Axes with a shared xaxis, then [`ax.twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) to create the twin Axes.

The offset spine on one of the shared axes is done using [this example on the matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax, offset):
    '''
    This function inspired by this example, to offset a twin axis spine. 
    link: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html
    '''
    ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", offset))
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

# First create your figure, with 3 subplots sharing the x axis.
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)

# make some room on the right for the twin axes
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)

# The easy ones, create the first twin axes on ax1 and ax2
ax1t = ax1.twinx()
ax2t = ax2.twinx()

# Create the twin axis on ax2 with an offset spine
ax2tb = ax2.twinx()
make_patch_spines_invisible(ax2tb, offset=1.15)

# Here I just set some axes limits to show the y axis scales are all independent
ax3.set_xlim(0, 900)

ax1.set_ylim(0, 2000)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 1000)
ax3.set_ylim(0, 50)

ax1t.set_ylim(0, 12)
ax2t.set_ylim(0, 12)
ax2tb.set_ylim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What happens with regards to independent legends? Do I just add those directly to the plot as before?

Comment: See here for some examples of wither adding separate legends, or combining legends: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484922/secondary-axis-with-twinx-how-to-add-to-legend